# Access Denied when installing Server 2003 server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, printing

Having an issue connecting to a Server 2003 print server with Windows 7 computers.  I get an "Access Denied" error when trying to connect.

A Microsoft article shows the exact problem and solution by modifying the group policy.  Trouble is I can only find the policy item in Server 2008, not 2003.  Any thoughts.

Here is the MS article that revers to:
  Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers\Point and Print Restrictions = Disabled

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753269.aspx

**UPDATE:** If we modify the above mentioned policy setting on the local Win 7 system all works fine.  Found this at a few other sites.  Problem is, I don't want to manually update 200 machines at the local policy level.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? Have you run RSOP or GPRESULTS to confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Have you downloaded [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en) and tried to manage the point and print option through group policy from a Windows 7 machine? You should be able to create a "point and print" GPO and apply it to your clients and have it work.

**ORIGINAL MESSAGE:**
Is your domain\forest operating at a Windows 2003 functional level? You should be able to install RSAT on Windows 7 and manage the policy from there assuming the functional level is 2003 or greater.

Comment: Also, as joeqwerty mentions in the comment above, make sure you run `gpresult /r` to confirm that the policy is being applied.